# How to align Frame number and Navigation symbols? Beamer

Tags: beamer

I feel that the frame number and navigation symbols are not vertically aligned, the former is a bit lower. Commands like `\vspace{}` do not work; why? How can I adjust them?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{default}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline} \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber \hspace{0.3cm}
    \insertslidenavigationsymbol \insertframenavigationsymbol \insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol \insertsectionnavigationsymbol \insertdocnavigationsymbol \insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol% 
}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{frame}{Frame}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, why the numbers are not perfectly aligned by default. Maybe it is because of the characters' own bounding box.

This is a hack using `adjustbox` for bottom alignment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usetheme{default}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{%
    \adjustbox{valign=b}{
    \usebeamerfont{footline} \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber \hspace{0.3cm}
    }
    \adjustbox{valign=b}{
    \insertslidenavigationsymbol \insertframenavigationsymbol \insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol \insertsectionnavigationsymbol \insertdocnavigationsymbol \insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol% 
    }
}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{frame}{Frame}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to use an additional package, you could also use two beamercolorboxes and adjust its parameter `dp=<length>` by hand.